# Impossible to read ESRI Shapefile using geemap.shp_to_ee (geemap)

Tags: google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

I'm working with Google Earth Engine Python API and geemap in an Anaconda environment. I'm trying to simply add a vector layer to my basemap. I'm following the Qiusheng Wu's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=131&v=OlNlqfj4uHo&feature=emb_logo). So I use the following code:

```
import ee
import geemap

Map = geemap.Map(center=[40, -2], zoom=6)
Map

shp_path = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Project/lineas_limite/SHP_ETRS89/recintos_autonomicas_inspire_peninbal_etrs89/'
shp_name = 'recintos_autonomicas_inspire_peninbal_etrs89.shp'

cv_region = geemap.shp_to_ee(shp_path + shp_name)
```

Here I obtain the following message:

**'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 13: invalid continuation byte**

```
Map.addLayer(cv_region, {}, 'Spain')
```

I installed the pyshp dependencies as in the tutorial using `pip install pyshp` and then I restarted the kernel. But the error still occurring.

```
**---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_2936\3789440705.py in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 Map.addLayer(cv_region, {}, 'US States')

~\anaconda3\envs\GEO\lib\site-packages\geemap\geemap.py in add_ee_layer(self, ee_object, vis_params, name, shown, opacity)
   1439         ):
   1440             err_str = "\n\nThe image argument in 'addLayer' function must be an instance of one of ee.Image, ee.Geometry, ee.Feature or ee.FeatureCollection."
-> 1441             raise AttributeError(err_str)
   1442 
   1443         if (

AttributeError: 

The image argument in 'addLayer' function must be an instance of one of ee.Image, ee.Geometry, ee.Feature or ee.FeatureCollection.**
```

I'm using the following `ee` and `geemap` versions:

```
print(ee.__version__)
print(geemap.__version__)

0.1.335
0.17.1
```

Comment: Try `geemap.shp_to_ee(shp_path + shp_name, encoding='latin-1')`